# Reconstruct vector field from python dictionary keyed by nested tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, nested, tuples

There's a dictionary in the following form:

```
vector_dict =  {((3, 4), 2): 4678, 
               ((0, 2), 1): 0,
               ...
                }
```

The tuple nested in the tuple corresponds to xy-coordinates. The next part is an integer with possible values n= 0, 1, 2, 3 representing the four main directions. The values keyed by that represent some magnitude.
So the first key value pair becomes:
Vector [1,0], located at x=3, y=4, scaled by 4,678.
I tried using pandas but at I can't get my head around it, how to properly extract this in a usable way.
Later I want to plot it broadly similar to the one on the right but completely filling the board:
[image]

Comment: you have a series of `('x', 'y')` points when each successive point is dictated by the position prior with the direction and magnitude of the move.  Your data doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Series constructor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.html) to load the data from a `dict`. Then you can [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to get the direction in axis 1. Lastly, [convert](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_tuples.html) the positional index into a [MultiIndex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.html).

```
d = {((3, 4), 2): 4678, ((0, 2), 1): 0}
df = pd.Series(d).unstack()
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index, names=['x', 'y'])

print(df)
```

yields

```
       1       2
x y             
0 2  0.0     NaN
3 4  NaN  4678.0
```